# GET request, with data

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the equivalent of the following browser-side GET request in Node?

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://test.com',
    type: 'GET',
    data: myData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

My best attempt is

```
http.get('http://test.com', function(response) {
   response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log(chunk);
   });
});
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass `data: myData` in the Node version. How can I pass data to `http.get` requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass it the full URL. you can create the URL by adding the query parameters yourself. There is a helper for making your own [Query Strings](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html). So it would be something like:

```
url = "http://test.com/?" + querystring.stringify(myData);
http.get(url, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the get method is by url, so you can add it to the url if you want

```
http.get('http://test.com?GetVariable='+myVal, function(response) {
   response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      console.log(chunk);
   });
});
```